# Turn on batteries with MOSFET problem

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Not really having any application in mind, I am playing with batteries and MOSFET. Here I want to turn on 2 batteries using a third battery. Here is the problem, when gate is HIGH, Va = 6.1v; Not the 8v that it should be since 4+4=8; Vb = 2.1v and Vds= 1.8v; Seems to me, Vgs is not high enough. Increasing Vgs sloved the problem, but clearly we are using 3 same kind of lithium batteries here, and changing the voltage is not an option. Now, when Vgs = 0, or LOW, strangely, Va= 2.2v now and Vb = -1.7v. This is very strange, indeed. I have no clue where the 2.2v and -1.7v came from.

[image]

Here is my improved version. When V3=4v or HIGH, Va=8v and Vb=4v; that is good. That is what I have expected, but when V3=0 or LOW, Va=2.27v and Vb=-1.7v; almost same result as the above circuit, so what is cause for this strange output and what is correct and properly way to use MOSFET to switch batteries in situation like that?

Comment: Why do you have a voltage source in the source circuit? Put M1 below V2.

Comment: @Brian Drummond  if I do that, then it's too simple. switch 1 battery instead of 2.

Comment: That's an N-channel enhancement mode Mosfet.  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_6.html     But you have it wired like it's a P-channel.  Try flipping it around and things may behave like you expect.    Anyhow, putting your MOSFET inbetween two series batteries in an attempt to control them is somewhat unorthodox as well.   Generally you'd find it easier if the two were in series directly connected, and the MOSFET sitting at either end (reference directly to ground or V+ rail).

Comment: As for 'why the odd voltages',  it's probably because you're forward-biasing the diode found inside the MOSFET in the configuration you have   i.e. the source V2 is being 'shorted' by the 1k resistor R2 so it's not really contributing the way you think it is.

Comment: Look here at page 5 fig.12 https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva948/slva948.pdf?ts=1600447646298&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.pl%252F

Answer (score 0):

Use bidirectional MOSFET switch

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRRVvY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or use it this way

[image]

Because to Turn-ON the P-channel MOSFET the voltage at the gate needs to be lower than the voltage at the source terminal.